# How to push to bitbucket using jgit

Tags: bitbucket, jgit

I am trying to push code to bitbucket using jgit. Clone is working with ssh, but to push -  I need to set credentials and I am getting "not authorized " error. I tried username,  password, ("Private-token", access-token) and app password also
While pushing after a successful clone, ii am getting "origin not found" error also
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

"Not authorized" might mean that you don't have permissions to push to the specified branch. E.g. there might be a policy to not allow to push directly into main branch. Usually developers should push to feature branches and then submit pull requests to ask for code review before merging to the main branch.

As for "origin not found" please check the remotes. The default name for remote repository is `origin`, but you might have it differently. Also it might be an issue with the command parameters. Please provide more details.

Comment: It's a fresh repository in the bitbucket.org cloud. I have not set any properties.  I am pushing to "master" branch, I am not using "origin" reference anywhere.  I am using ssh to clone, but to push- I have to use a credential manager where it's failing to authenticate and sometimes origin not found issue

Comment: Is there a way to push using ssh itself in Jgit? Clone and push have to use same method?

Comment: So you initially cloned the repository from BitBucket and now you are trying to push your local changes back? Then the same URL is used for fetching/pushing. You can configure a separate URL for push with `git remote set-url --push ...` command. Or with `setUriType` method in JGit.

Comment: For clone, when I tried with https url and credentials,  access-token, app-password , it did not work. Seturitype in jgit has to be on some operation right?  Like on clone, we use seturitype for example .

Comment: Using jgit, can we push with ssh access? Without using credential manager

Comment: Can you try a clone and push using jgit on a bitbucket.org repo?

Comment: How did you authenticate when cloning the repository with SSH? I cannot clone/push right now, will be able to try in about 8 hours.

Comment: For ssh, it automatically picks up the ssh keys. The same ssh keys should be added in the bitbucket.  Please try when you can and let me know

Comment: did you get a chance to try out?